# Unable to serialize POJO to XML using Jackson

Tags: jackson

I am learning to use Jackson in Java to serialize and deserialize XML. I am just trying to follow a simple example but it is throwing an exception which I am not sure what it is pointing to. Can somebody please help me what I am missing. As per my understanding maven should pull in all relevant dependency for Jackson.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person")
public class Person {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    public String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "age")
    public int age;

    Person(final String n, int a){
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
}
```

```
ObjectMapper xmlMapper =  XmlMapper.builder().build();

Person p = new Person("sa", 12);

String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(p);
```

I am getting following exception on line

```
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(p);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.GeneratorBase.<init>(ILcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/ObjectCodec;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/IOContext;)V
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator.<init>(ToXmlGenerator.java:228)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:527)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory.createGenerator(XmlFactory.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.createGenerator(ObjectMapper.java:1188)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3821)
```

Following is my maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: *java.lang.NoSuchMethodError* indicates incompatible library versions. From the stacktarce i would say *jackson-dataformat-xml* and *jackson-core*

Comment: So you mean some other dependency is picking a different Jackson library? If so is there a easy way to resolve conflict or I need to manually remove that dependency

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. *If so is there a easy way to resolve conflict or I need to manually remove that dependency* Hard to say without knowing where it comes from. But one solution is to use an other version of *jackson-dataformat-xml* which is compatible to your *jackson-core* library

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me see how I can get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was not able to figure out which dependency was pulling older version of jackson-core and other libraries, I explicitly added latest version of all. It started working after that.